# AngularJs ng-repeat does not order time list after scope change

Tags: angularjs

I try to reorder ng-repeat list after $scope change

```
<div ng-repeat="item in model.itemList  | orderBy:order">
  <input ng-blur="setOrder('start')"
         ng-change="timeSpanChange(item.start,start.newTime);"
         ng-model="start.newTime" ng-value="item.start|showTimeSpan"
         type="time" />
</div>
```

And I have angular code:

```
app.controller('ctl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.order = 'start';
    $scope.model =  {
        "itemList": [
            { "start":new Date(2000,01,01,10,00,00) },
            { "start":new Date(2000,01,01,11,00,00) },
            { "start":new Date(2000,01,01,12,00,00) }
        ]
    }

    $scope.setOrder = function (order) {
        $scope.order = order;
    };

    $scope.timeSpanChange = function (item, time) {
        item.Hours = time.getHours();
        item.Minutes = time.getMinutes();            
    };

}).filter('showTimeSpan', function () {
    return function (time) {
        return String(time.Hours).padStart(2, '0') + ":" + String(time.Minutes).padStart(2, '0');
    };
});
```

I see that model has change after ng-blur, but ng-repeat is still ordered as on first load

What i'm doing wrong, should I refresh scope before reorder?

Comment: You have set the value of the order in scope as $scope.order = 'start'; and setting the same value on ng-blur as ng-blur="setOrder('start')" which remain same. List has already rendered with an order by 'start' and again you are setting the same value of order by 'start' which is no change in old state/data.

Comment: Don't use `ng-model` and `ng-value` on the same element. Use `ng-model` for two-way binding; `ng-value` for one-way binding.

Answer (score 0):

order should be a property in the itemList. I'm assuming you are not changing the sort order.

`<div ng-repeat="item in model.itemList  | orderBy:'start'">`

Comment: The controller sets the order -- `$scope.order = 'start';`. It is quite common to use a scope variable so that the user can change the column by which a table is ordered.

Answer (score 0):

The `orderBy` filter sorts JavaScript [Date objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) by date and time. Use a custom predicate function to sort by time only:

```
$scope.timeOnlyFn = function(item) {
  var timeOnly = item.datetime.valueOf() % (24*60*60*1000);
  return timeOnly;
}
```

### [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/IvVAg8JMe9u4WiR1Cm0r?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.controller('ctrl', function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.order = 'datetime';
    $scope.model =  {
        "itemList": [
            { "datetime": new Date("2019-02-07T09:00"), name: "Baker" },
            { "datetime": new Date("2019-07-07T08:00"), name: "Charlie" },
            { "datetime": new Date("2019-02-07T10:00"), name: "Adam" }
        ]
    }
    
    $scope.timeOnlyFn = function(item) {
      var timeOnly = item.datetime.valueOf() % (24*60*60*1000);
      return timeOnly;
    }

    $scope.setOrder = function (order) {
        $scope.order = order;
    };
});
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <div ng-repeat="item in model.itemList  | orderBy:order">
    <input ng-model="item.datetime" type="date" />
    <input ng-model="item.datetime" type="time" />
    {{item.name}}
  </div>
  
<br>
  <button ng-click="order='name'">Order by Name</button>
  <button ng-click="order='datetime'">Order by DateTime</button>
  <button ng-click="order=timeOnlyFn">Order by TimeOnly</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot georgeawg, that's exactly what I need, but I suppose my problem starts in the model.

In fact I'm getting json from controller and it isn't UTC but C# TimeSpan object `{"Hours":16,"Minutes":8,"Seconds":45,"Milliseconds":.....`, that's why i used ng filter to map it with `<input type='time'>`

Is the properly way to make two-way binding model property with C# time span; or
should I convert it in controller?